# with pgfplots gives an error when I restrict the range but not when I have an unrestricted range

Tags: pgfplots

The following example compiles fine for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
                 %%ymax=10,
                 ymin=-7,
                 ]
       \addplot [domain=-2:-1.001,   samples=25]  {(\x-1)/(\x^2-1)};
       \addplot [domain=-0.999:0.999,samples=20]  {(\x-1)/(\x^2-1)};
       \addplot [domain=1.001:2,     samples=25]  {(\x-1)/(\x^2-1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But when I uncomment the line `ymax=10`, I get the following error:

```
! Dimension too large.
<recently read> \pgf@yy 

l.14     \end{axis}

?
```

What's happening here?  I would like not to have to restrict the domains.

Comment: I guess you are getting too close to `0/0`... If I uncomment the `ymax=10` line and change the domains to `-2:-1.01`, `-0.99:0.99`, and `1.01:2` I get no error with `pdflatex`

Comment: @darthbith But why is getting too close to `0/0` only a problem when I restrict the `ymax`.  If it's getting too close with `ymax` set, shouldn't it be getting to close without `ymax` set?

Comment: Didn't run it but usually the plot shrinks down when you add more space in the limits of axes. And as the individual small subpaths shrink too, at some point you get very short paths that trips TeX.

Comment: @A.Ellett Interestingly, if you change to `ymin=-10` and uncomment the `ymax=10` with your domains, there is no error, but if `ymin=-9`, again the error shows up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the `ymax` to `10`, you're in effect setting the y unit vector to about `20 pt` (the default `height` is `207 pt`). Since your highest point has a value of ca. `1000`, this ends up being `20000 pt` above the axis origin, which is too far for TeX to handle. If you let PGFPlots scale the unit vector automatically by not prescribing a value for `ymax`, the problem disappears.

To avoid this problem, in addition to `ymax=10`, use `restrict y to domain=-inf:20`. This will filter out the point that's causing the trouble.

Using this approach, you can even use a single `\addplot` command for the entire plot:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,
                 restrict y to domain=-20:20,
                 ymin=-10,
                 ymax=10,
                 ]
       \addplot [domain=-2:2, samples=100]  {(\x-1)/(\x^2-1)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of what's happening and for showing how to do this in one `\addplot`.